# cannot loop through json Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Tags: json, url

I cant manage to loop through my json that i have setup at this url i just keep getting the following error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

here is my json http://example.com/api/?email=info@example.co.uk&format=json

i am trying to pull it in from the following code.

//json

```
var json_feed = 'http://example.com/api/?email=info@example.co.uk&format=json&callback=?';

$.getJSON(json_feed, function(json) {

       console.log(json);

});​
```

Where am i going wrong can someone advise.

Manage to get it to work with the following..

php

```
header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
         echo json_encode($buckets);
```

jquery

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://example.com/api/?email=info@example.co.uk&format=json',
  success: function(data) {

    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

Comment: I get 500 error when I try to navigate to this url. Are you sure that it supports JSONP?

Comment: hi thanks for the reply i have fixed the url could you take another look please

Comment: Well the url you have shown returns JSON, not JSONP. So your AJAX call cannot possibly work. Due to the same origin policy restriction you cannot send cross domain AJAX calls unless the server sends JSONP response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url you have shown doesn't returns JSON but not JSONP. Due to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) restriction you cannot send cross domain AJAX calls unless the server supports JSONP. You have added the `callback=?` parameter to the url which is OK from the client side perspective as jQuery will send it, but the server seems to completely ignore it and it returns JSON instead of wrapping this JSON into the callback passed as parameter (which is JSONP).

You should probably contact the authors of the site you are trying to access or read the documentation of the API they are exposing (if any) to see if it supports JSONP.